# jquery UI dialog opening behind parent ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

I have a jquery UI dialog (opened using ajax). On that dialog I have some content and a button that opens (again using ajax) another ui dialog.

The initial press of the button opens the second dialog fine. If I close that second dialog and press the button again, the dialog opens but it is hidden behind the first dialog.

Is there anything I can do in jquery to force that dialog to focus? I would never want it to be behind that original window.

Code:

Code for first dialog...

```
$('#searchUsers').autocomplete({
    source: "/gpcadmin/Roles/Lookup",
    minLength: 0,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $('#searchUsers').val(ui.item.label);

        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var id = ui.item.value;
        $.ajax({           
            url: "/gpcadmin/Users/UserDashboard/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#my-dialog2").html(data);
                $('#my-dialog2').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: "1200px",
                    height: 700,
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#my-dialog2").dialog("close");
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Code on first dialog for calling second dialog:

```
$("#quickButton1").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/gpcadmin/Roles/cardOfficersui/" + $(this).data("task-id"),
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#my-dialog23").html(data);
            $('#my-dialog23').dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: "600px",
                height: 400,
                close: function (event, ui) {

                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different z-indexes. For example:

```
$('#my-dialog23').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: "600px",
            height: 400,
            close: function (event, ui) {

            },
            zIndex:500
        });


$('#my-dialog2').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: "1200px",
                    height: 700,
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#my-dialog2").dialog("close");
                    },
                     zIndex:501
                });
```